# Aws serverless - cost of switching region

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently in the middle of development for aws serverless backend(cognito,lambda,api Gateway,dynamodb,s3).
.
I find that I choose the wrong region before.

Question:
1.is there any difference when using different region in Aws development?
2.is the cost high when changing region in the middle of development(re-creating the db/lambda function/api gateway)
3.what is the proper approach to switch to another region with the same serverless setting/config I am using now?

Comment: What potential "high costs" are you thinking about here? Do you have PB of data in S3 or TB in DynamoDB that you need to move across regions? You say you're in the dev phase right now. Is this any more than simply deleting your region1 serverless deployments and assets and then pointing your deployment at region2 and re-deploying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### 1. Cost and latency will differ.

Some services in AWS have different costs in different regions. Some services are global (all regions) by default - for example S3. There are some useful charts on [this blog post](https://www.concurrencylabs.com/blog/choose-your-aws-region-wisely/), including the following diagram on data transfer out cost differences by region:
[image]

If your customer is in region A and is requesting services in region B then the response will take ever so slightly longer. It’s not usually long enough to warrant concern. Though, using CloudFront between the service and customer will reduce the slow down - and in many cases make for a faster service so it’s worth doing even if customer and service are in the same region.

### 2. It depends

If you’re creating these services manually then you’d have to spend that time in the console for the new region again. Time is money, and you’ll maybe make a mistake in setup - you’re only human.

If you’re creating these services in code - using CloudFormation (or AWS CDK, serverless.com, terraform or the many other ways to do Infrastructure as Code) then it won’t cost anything. You would have a single command (maybe a few) which will reproduce your infrastructure in any region.

Then, you’ll need to migrate data. This is the unavoidable cost. If you’ve beeen running in region A for any time and then move to region B you will need to transfer the data. That’ll require a script to take the data out of dynamo and put it into the new one.

### 3. Use Infrastructure as Code and always be prepared for data migration

Have a look at AWS CDK. It allows you to define your services in either Java, Python, or JavaScript and has some nice tutorials. https://cdkworkshop.com/

As you code, build out your scripts to extract the data from dynamo. This is useful to have even if you don’t transfer tl a different region - maybe you want to run a copy in a staging/dev environment.

### 4. New services are not released in all regions at the same time

If you are using a brand new service or a new feature of an existing service, it might not yet be available in each region. Choose a region that supports all desired services and features. For example, in [this Dec 2019 announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/12/aws-transit-gateway-supports-inter-region-peering/) by AWS about Inter-Region peering for Transit Gateway, it says this feature was released to "US East (N. Virginia), US East (Ohio), US West (Oregon), EU (Ireland), and EU (Frankfurt) AWS Regions" and the others would come soon.